# App crash downloaded from App Store, TestFlight works well

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase, app-store, testflight

My app works well on simulators, real device in dev mode, also works well on TestFlight, so I decided to publish them, review also gone well.
I downloaded application from App Store and application crash every time after few second. (Application crash also on client's devices).

I don't understand what's going on.

This is crash log from my iPhone:

```
Incident Identifier: 8EE855FB-6A24-4330-8A80-CDEC28579C49
CrashReporter Key:   d63275a612c8977a490a510b930e34efb80e38e5
Hardware Model:      iPhone8,1
Process:             Player [2451]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A73FAFBC-D6B1-4F28-ACB9-528CCE673995/Player.app/Player
Identifier:          com.facebook.APPLICATION_NAMEPlayerApp
Version:             9 (1.5)
AppStoreTools:       10B63
AppVariant:          1:iPhone8,1:9
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Non UI
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.facebook.APPLICATION_NAMEPlayerApp [644]


Date/Time:           2018-11-21 23:39:19.7942 +0100
Launch Time:         2018-11-21 23:39:14.1457 +0100
OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.1 (16B92)
Baseband Version:    5.21.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  1

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1e8b8bea0 __exceptionPreprocess + 228
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1e7d5da40 objc_exception_throw + 55
2   Player                          0x1043d36c0 0x1043a0000 + 210624
3   Player                          0x1043d1188 0x1043a0000 + 201096
4   CoreFoundation                  0x1e8b93600 __invoking___ + 143
5   CoreFoundation                  0x1e8a71530 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 291
6   CoreFoundation                  0x1e8a72114 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 59
7   Player                          0x1043e7afc 0x1043a0000 + 293628
8   Player                          0x10442c1d0 0x1043a0000 + 573904
9   Player                          0x10442bf2c 0x1043a0000 + 573228
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x1e85c56c8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 23
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x1e85c6484 _dispatch_client_callout + 15
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x1e856dbe0 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 591
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x1e856e728 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 431
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x1e8576ec8 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 599
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1e87a80dc _pthread_wqthread + 311
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1e87aacec start_wqthread + 3


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e8717ed0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e87173a8 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001e8b1bbc4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001e8b16a60 __CFRunLoopRun + 1396
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001e8b161cc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5   GraphicsServices                0x00000001ead8d584 GSEventRunModal + 100
6   UIKitCore                       0x0000000215c11054 UIApplicationMain + 212
7   Player                          0x00000001043a7a64 0x1043a0000 + 31332
8   libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001e85d6bb4 start + 4

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue
Thread 1 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e8723104 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e879e070 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 380
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001e867ad78 abort + 140
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001e7d44f78 __cxa_bad_cast + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001e7d45120 default_unexpected_handler+ 8480 () + 0
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001e7d5de48 _objc_terminate+ 28232 () + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001e7d510fc std::__terminate(void (*)+ 57596 ()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001e7d51188 std::terminate+ 57736 () + 84
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001e85c6498 _dispatch_client_callout + 36
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001e856dbe0 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 592
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001e856e728 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 432
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001e8576ec8 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 600
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e87a80dc _pthread_wqthread + 312
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e87aacec start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e87aace8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e87aace8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e87aace8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e87aace8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e87aace8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e8717ed0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e87173a8 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001e8b1bbc4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001e8b16a60 __CFRunLoopRun + 1396
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001e8b161cc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5   Foundation                      0x00000001e950b404 -[NSRunLoop+ 33796 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 300
6   Foundation                      0x00000001e950b2b0 -[NSRunLoop+ 33456 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 148
7   UIKitCore                       0x0000000215cfe808 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8   Foundation                      0x00000001e963e1ac __NSThread__start__ + 1040
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e87a72ac _pthread_body + 128
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e87a720c _pthread_start + 48
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e87aacf4 thread_start + 4

Thread 8 name:  com.facebook.react.JavaScript
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e8717ed0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e87173a8 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001e8b1bbc4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001e8b16a60 __CFRunLoopRun + 1396
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001e8b161cc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5   Player                          0x00000001043bb2d0 0x1043a0000 + 111312
6   Foundation                      0x00000001e963e1ac __NSThread__start__ + 1040
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e87a72ac _pthread_body + 128
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e87a720c _pthread_start + 48
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e87aacf4 thread_start + 4

Thread 9 name:  JavaScriptCore bmalloc scavenger
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e8722f0c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e879fcd8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001e7cf04d0 std::__1::condition_variable::wait+ 34000 (std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 24
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001efebe9b8 void std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex> >+ 379320 (std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>&) + 104
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001efec2aac bmalloc::Scavenger::threadRunLoop+ 395948 () + 176
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001efec21e0 bmalloc::Scavenger::Scavenger+ 393696 (std::__1::lock_guard<bmalloc::Mutex>&) + 0
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001efec3c8c std::__1::__thread_specific_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct>::set_pointer+ 400524 (std::__1::__thread_struct*) + 0
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e87a72ac _pthread_body + 128
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e87a720c _pthread_start + 48
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e87aacf4 thread_start + 4

Thread 10 name:  GAIThread
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e8717ed0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e87173a8 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001e8b1bbc4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001e8b16a60 __CFRunLoopRun + 1396
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001e8b161cc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5   Foundation                      0x00000001e950b404 -[NSRunLoop+ 33796 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 300
6   Foundation                      0x00000001e9546df4 -[NSRunLoop+ 278004 (NSRunLoop) run] + 88
7   Player                          0x00000001044b9aa4 0x1043a0000 + 1153700
8   Foundation                      0x00000001e963e1ac __NSThread__start__ + 1040
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e87a72ac _pthread_body + 128
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e87a720c _pthread_start + 48
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e87aacf4 thread_start + 4

Thread 11 name:  WTF::AutomaticThread
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e8722f0c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e879fcd8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001efeacb48 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait+ 305992 (WTF::Mutex&, WTF::WallTime) + 148
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001efe93d10 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void + 204048 ()> const&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 2004
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001efe6d654 bool WTF::Condition::waitUntil<WTF::Lock>+ 46676 (WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 184
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001efe6d9f4 WTF::Function<void ()>::CallableWrapper<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::AbstractLocker const&)::$_0>::call+ 47604 () + 216
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001efeaad60 WTF::Thread::entryPoint+ 298336 (WTF::Thread::NewThreadContext*) + 256
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001efeac2c8 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint+ 303816 (void*) + 12
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e87a72ac _pthread_body + 128
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e87a720c _pthread_start + 48
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e87aacf4 thread_start + 4

Thread 12 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e8717ed0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e87173a8 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001e8b1bbc4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001e8b16a60 __CFRunLoopRun + 1396
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001e8b161cc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5   CFNetwork                       0x00000001e9137834 -[__CoreSchedulingSetRunnable runForever] + 212
6   Foundation                      0x00000001e963e1ac __NSThread__start__ + 1040
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e87a72ac _pthread_body + 128
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e87a720c _pthread_start + 48
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e87aacf4 thread_start + 4

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e87aace8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 14 name:  JSC Heap Collector Thread
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e8722f0c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e879fcd8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001efeacb48 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait+ 305992 (WTF::Mutex&, WTF::WallTime) + 148
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001efe93d10 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void + 204048 ()> const&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 2004
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001efe6d654 bool WTF::Condition::waitUntil<WTF::Lock>+ 46676 (WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 184
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001efe6d9f4 WTF::Function<void ()>::CallableWrapper<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::AbstractLocker const&)::$_0>::call+ 47604 () + 216
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001efeaad60 WTF::Thread::entryPoint+ 298336 (WTF::Thread::NewThreadContext*) + 256
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001efeac2c8 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint+ 303816 (void*) + 12
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e87a72ac _pthread_body + 128
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e87a720c _pthread_start + 48
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e87aacf4 thread_start + 4

Thread 1 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000002824027b7
    x4: 0x00000001e7d54b81   x5: 0x000000016bae6460   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x0000000000000c00   x9: 0x00000001e87a2870  x10: 0x00000001e879def4  x11: 0x0000000000000003
   x12: 0x000000000000004f  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0000000000000015
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x000000016bae7000  x21: 0x000000016bae6460  x22: 0x0000000000001003  x23: 0x000000016bae70e0
   x24: 0x0000000281f73ec0  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x000000016bae70e0   fp: 0x000000016bae63c0   lr: 0x00000001e879e070
    sp: 0x000000016bae6390   pc: 0x00000001e8723104 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

and here package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Player",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "android": "react-native run-android"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/redux-persist": "^4.3.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.1.1",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "iap-receipt-validator": "^1.0.6",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "querystring": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "16.5.1",
    "react-native": "0.56.1",
    "react-native-blur": "^3.2.2",
    "react-native-blur-overlay": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-config": "^0.11.5",
    "react-native-cookies": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-google-analytics-bridge": "^6.1.0",
    "react-native-in-app-utils": "^6.0.1",
    "react-native-music-control": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-orientation": "^3.1.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-video": "^3.2.1",
    "react-navigation": "^2.2.0",
    "react-navigation-fluid-transitions": "^0.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-native": "^4.3.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^10.3.1",
    "@types/react": "^16.3.16",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.55.17",
    "@types/react-native-video": "^2.0.6",
    "@types/react-navigation": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/react-redux": "^6.0.2",
    "@types/react-router-native": "^4.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "23.0.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^5.0.2",
    "jest": "23.1.0",
    "prettier": "^1.13.4",
    "react-native-typescript-transformer": "^1.2.10",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1",
    "typescript": "^2.9.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts"
    ]
  }
}
```

Android version works well also on production.

Comment: Symbolicate please.

Comment: Not your problem, but why did you use `com.facebook` as the first part of your bundle ID?  I presume this application isn't published by Facebook.  You should use your own domain for Bundle IDs (but it is too late to change it now)

Comment: You may be able to do a better debugging if you setup something like crashlytics https://medium.com/delivery-com-engineering/add-crashlytics-to-your-react-native-ios-app-69a983a9062a

Comment: btw @matt was referring to this I think 
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that cache or database problem in previous versions?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved.
I'm downloading products from Apple and actual prices(from my subscriptions), all works fine on Testflight but I don't know why, this options is blocked on production and I don't have any catch if app can't download products... so app after few seconds was crash.